# Problema al crear matriz 3x3 con nodos

Tags: c, matrices

El codigo debe hacer una "matriz" de 3 x 3 con nodos que apunten a siguiente, anterior, arriba y abajo, aparte de tener un valor
Yo lo hice en una estructura llamada Nodo y lo llene con puros if, pero al momento de compilarlo me aparece este error

```
C:\Users\Odec\Desktop\ETS\Cubo>gcc cubo2.c

cubo2.c: In function 'main':

cubo2.c:31:10: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     raiz = crea_Nodo();

cubo2.c:32:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     actual = crea_Nodo();            

cubo2.c:33:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     aux = crea_Nodo();        

cubo2.c:34:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     primeroF=crea_Nodo();             

cubo2.c:35:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     ant=crea_Nodo();

cubo2.c:43:32: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct
Nodo'
             scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo {
    int valor;
    struct Nodo *arriba;
    struct Nodo *abajo;
    struct Nodo *izquierda;
    struct Nodo *derecha;
}*Nodo;

Nodo crea_Nodo(){
    Nodo N;
    N=(Nodo)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if(N==NULL){
        printf("No hay memoria disponible\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    N->arriba=NULL;
    N->abajo=NULL;
    N->izquierda=NULL;
    N->derecha=NULL;
    N->valor=0;
    return N;
}

int main() {
    struct Nodo *raiz, *actual, *aux, *primeroF, *ant;
    int i, j, k, suma;

    raiz = crea_Nodo();
    actual = crea_Nodo();
    aux = crea_Nodo();
    primeroF=crea_Nodo();
    ant=crea_Nodo();
    actual = raiz;

    // Ingreso de valores
    for (k=0; k<3; k++){
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {        
        if(i==0 && k==0){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->derecha=crea_Nodo();
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
            ant=actual;
            actual=actual->derecha;
            primeroF=ant;
        }else if (i==2 && k==0){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->izquierda=ant;
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
        }else if(k==0){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->derecha=crea_Nodo();
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
            actual->izquierda=ant;
            ant=actual;
            actual=actual->derecha;
        }else if(i==0 && k==1){
            actual=primeroF->abajo;
            ant=primeroF;
            primeroF=actual;
            //ponemos a actual en la coordenada (1,0)
            ant=ant->derecha->abajo;
            actual->derecha=ant;
            ant->izquierda=actual;
            ant=ant->arriba;
            ant->abajo->arriba=ant;
            ant=ant->izquierda;
            actual->arriba=ant;
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
            actual=actual->derecha;

        }else if(i==2 && k==1){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
            ant=primeroF;
            actual=ant->abajo;
            primeroF=actual;
        }else if(k==1){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            ant=ant->derecha->derecha;
            ant=ant->abajo;
            actual->derecha=ant;
            actual->abajo=crea_Nodo();
            ant->izquierda=actual;
            ant=ant->arriba;
            ant->abajo->arriba=ant;
            actual=actual->derecha;
        }else if(i==0 && k==2){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            actual->arriba=ant;
            ant=ant->derecha->abajo;
            ant->izquierda=actual;
            actual->derecha=ant;
            ant=ant->arriba;
            ant->abajo->arriba=ant;
            actual=actual->derecha;
        }else if(i==2 && k==2){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
        }else if(k==2){
            printf("Ingrese el valor para el nodo (%d,%d): ", k, i);
            scanf("%d", &actual->valor);
            ant=ant->derecha;
            ant=ant->abajo;
            actual->derecha=ant;
            ant->izquierda=actual;
            ant=ant->arriba;
            ant->abajo->arriba=ant;
            actual=actual->derecha;
        }
    }

    }

    // Cálculo de la suma por fila
    aux = raiz;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        suma=((aux->valor)+(aux->derecha->valor)+(aux->derecha->derecha->valor));
        printf("Suma de la fila %d es %d\n", i, suma);
        aux = aux->abajo;
    }

    // Cálculo de la suma por columna
    actual = raiz;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        suma=((aux->valor)+(aux->abajo->valor)+(aux->abajo->abajo->valor));
        printf("Suma de la columna %d es %d\n", i, suma);
        aux = aux->derecha;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

¡¡¡Gracias de antemano!!!

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene errores de tipo sencillos de corregir, pero además posiblemente tenga errores de lógica pues el hecho de que hayas usado tantos `if` anidados ya es mala señal, y además al ejecutarlo (una vez corregidos los errores de tipo) produce un fallo de segmentación en la segunda iteración del bucle sobre `k`.

Voy a indicarte cómo corregir los errores de tipo para que al menos tengas una versión compilable que después puedas estudiar bajo un depurador para ejecutarla paso a paso y descubrir ya por tí mismo a qué se debe la excepción.

El error de tipo proviene de que has definido el tipo `struct nodo` (como consecuencia de la declaración que comienza por `typedef struct nodo {...`) y más adelante has definido el tipo `Nodo` como un equivalente a `struct nodo *`, es decir como un puntero a la estructura `nodo` (debido a la línea  `} *Nodo;`)

Así pues tienes dos tipos de nombre similar que te han llevado a confusión:

- Tipo `struct nodo`: es una estructura
- Tipo `Nodo`: es un puntero a una estructura.

Así pues, cuando dentro la estructura declaras un campo del tipo `struct Node *`, eso estaría mal, y debería ser `struct node *`. Así pues tu estructura queda así:

```
typedef struct nodo {
    int valor;
    struct nodo *arriba;
    struct nodo *abajo;
    struct nodo *izquierda;
    struct nodo *derecha;
} *Nodo;
```

Además de ese cambio, cuando más adelante declaras tus variables en `main`:

```
    struct Nodo *raiz, *actual, *aux, *primeroF, *ant;
```

de nuevo está mal y debería ser:

```
    struct nodo *raiz, *actual, *aux, *primeroF, *ant;
```

o incluso, si prefieres:

```
    Nodo raiz, actual, aux, primeroF, ant;
```

dado que vía `typedef` habías definido `struct nodo *` como equivalente a `Nodo`.

Con estos cambios desaparecen los errores de compilación, si bien aparecen errores en tiempo de ejecución debido probablemente a una lógica defectuosa que tendrás que depurar. Te aconsejo además refactorizar el código para eliminar todos esos condicionales.

Comment: OMG gracias!!! Respecto a los if por montones, el profesor nos pidio que hicieramos el programa asi, se que el error de segmentación es SIGSEGV que habla de una violacion a la memoria de un puntero
Ahora como mejoro mi logica? En verdad llevo tiempo programando pero no consigo mejorar

Comment: La violación de segmento efectivamente indica que estás intentando usar un puntero que en realidad no ha sido asignado. Probablemente en alguna parte de ese código laberíntico, por ejemplo cuando haces `ant=ant->derecha->abajo;` acabas asignando el valor `NULL` a `ant` (si el nodo a su derecha no tiene nodo abajo, en este caso). A partir de ahí, cuando intentes `ant=ant->abajo;` tendrás una violación, pues `ant->abajo` sería en realidad `NULL->abajo` lo que es ilegal porque NULL no apunta a una estructura adecuada.

Comment: Entender cómo acaba llegando el valor NULL a una variable en la que tú esperabas otra cosa es complicado. O bien ejecutas tu código paso a paso en un depurador y vas examinando en cada paso los valores de todas las variables para descubrir el punto en que razonaste mal y la variable tiene un valor distinto del que habías supuesto, o bien si no sabes usar un depurador deberás ejecutar el código paso a paso "en tu cabeza", (o con papel y lápiz) apuntando cómo van cambiando de valor todas las variables en cada paso.